# How to place elements closer in a linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have an activity like this:

[image]

As you can see, the bottom below the checkboxes doesn't fit in the screen. How can I make the checkboxes get closer in the linearlayout?

And here is the XML (just the checkboxes + button):

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="591dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.20" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="@string/madurez_2" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/gestion_configuracion"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/medicion_analisis"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/monitorizacion_control"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/planificacion_proyecto"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/aseguramiento_calidad"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/gestion_requisitos"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:text="@string/gestion_acuerdos"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="142dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/comenzar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
```

You can add a top padding with a minus (-) sign on all of your checkboxes, exept for the first one on top, in these case -10, but you can chose whatever works for you ....that should put them  closer

Answer (score 0):

set margin of each checkbox to zero